# hash tags in urls and hyperlinks

Tags: url, hyperlink, urlencode, hashtag

I created a hyperlink to a file.  the file name contains hashtags as a means to separate information.

```
<a href="upload/1427853638#0#file#A101.pdf"><div style="height:100%;width:100%">.</div></a>
```

translated to...

```
http://localhost/dir/upload/1427853638#0#file#A101.pdf
```

Is this a "legal" name in a URL?  Im getting a "file not found" error

`The requested URL /dir/upload/1427853638 was not found on this server.`

So, clearly the # has another meaning in the URL (I understand now, its a location hash property). Is there a way to get this to work, or do i need to use another character besides the # in the file names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `#` is a special character in the URL semantic (it's used to provide an internal anchor in a HTML page), it should be URL-encoded into `%23`.

Your URL should be: `http://localhost/dir/upload/1427853638%230%23file%23A101.pdf`.

NB: you can find an online URL encoder here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/